# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, azure-pipelines

I want to configure selenium test automation suite(selenium cucumber maven project) as pipeline and run it in Azure-Devops. While running the pipeline faced below error:

```
Verification of Weblogin_TC1(Login to Web Application)  Time elapsed: 42.601 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

This error is pointing to the below line of code:

```
driver.get("app url");
```

Please provide me the way to overcome this

Comment: Whether you can run the test successfully on your local machine? If you can, try to set up a self-hosted agent on this local machine and use it to run the pipeline. Then check if it works.

Comment: when I run the test suite directly from spring tool suite then also it executes but facing this issue while executing from azure-pipeline

Comment: When you run your test on the pipeline, it essentially calls some commands on the agent. This is the same as running the test directly through command on your local machine. The main difference is the running environment. In order to know whether this issue is related to your project itself or the environment, please use command directly on your local machine to run your test.  If the test can run successfully using commands locally, set up a self-hosted agent on this machine, run the same commands in the pipeline and use this self-hosted agent to run the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

My hunch is that the URL you have provided is not a fully qualified URL.

Example:

Incorrect:

```
driver.get("www.google.com/");
```

Correct:

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
```

Comment: due to policy, wasn't able to share complete url here but in the code I'm passing fully qualified URL to driver

Comment: Does the URL open successfully if you open it manually from a browser?

Comment: yes it opens. Also when I run the test suite directly from spring tool suite then also it executes but facing this issue while executing from azure-pipeline

Comment: Also in local browser able to access the URL properly but in azure-pipeline, I checked the error message screenshot and it is showing as "can't reach this page"